# XAMPP MAC OS PHP GD Does Not Installed

Tags: php, macos, xampp

I have a problem with my mac. I am installing a fresh install of XAMPP through homebrew.

```
brew install --cask xampp
```

The problem is the GD is not installed correctly.

```
Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imagecreatefromjpeg()
```

I have tried to reinstall PHP through homebrew but the result is same. I have checked the PHP info and here is the gd result

[image]

Comment: You do not have **JPEG Support** `enabled` in your gd but you want to use `imagecreatefromjpeg()`

Comment: do you have any idea? I am using fresh install of XAMPP through homebrew. Nothing modified here.

Comment: In my understanding some versions of XAMPP has this issue . See [this_link](https://community.apachefriends.org/f/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=78868)

Comment: Download and install a differernt version of XAMPP on your mac and see the result please. See this [link](https://www.apachefriends.org/download.html)